# How I can transpiled my JSX code into JS object?

Tags: javascript, jsx, babeljs

I want create my version of React from scratch, but each manual says something like:
"so we write on JSX like that and take babel which the transpiled our code into JS". 
I would like to understand how this magic works. I mean how this:

```js
const div = <div id='JSX'> Example </div>
```

becomes this:

```js
div = ('div', {id='JSX'}, 'Example');
```

I see it something like this:

```js
function convertor(div){
  //code 
  return ObjectRepresentationOfDiv
}
```

But how I can pass the argument into convertor function without "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" ?

Answer (score 0):

The magic happens via webpack with babel plugins typically.

share your webpack.config.js to see whats in there if you are looking to get it up and running.

The below doc is prob what you are looking to read:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/

The source code for that can be found here if you want a deeper understanding.

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/src/index.js